Unexpected casting exception when using F# Seq.cast
A C# library
public class A
{
    public static implicit operator B(A a) => new B();
}

public class B
{
}

Is used in this F# code
let someAs = [A(); A(); A()]

let someBs1 = someAs |> Seq.map (fun a -> A.op_Implicit(a)) |> List.ofSeq
let someBs2 = Seq.cast<B> someAs |> List.ofSeq //Unable to cast A to B

Contrary to my expectations, Seq.cast fails to use the implicit operator. Is this expected?

Not an experienced F# developer but if Seq.cast is using Enumerable.Cast then yes it's expected, because Enumerable.Cast uses as and "User defined conversions aren't considered by the is and as operators" - MSDN

Support for implicit operators is limited in F#. In a nutshell, F# will invoke op_Implicit automatically when you are calling a method with known types for both source and target, such as:
// C#
public class C
{
    public static void UseB(B b) { }
}

// F#
C.UseB(A())

Your code isn't trying to pass an instance of A to a method that expects a B, so F# doesn't call op_Implicit for you automatically.
